# Action of forum doesn't get ID

Tags: php, forum

I have this set in top of page

```
if (isset($_GET["edit"]) and !empty($_GET["edit"])) {
   $edit_id=(int)$_GET["edit"];
   $edit_id=sanitize($edit_id);
}
```

and then i do this with my action on the topbar it shows the number of `id`
but if i do ""view source" i see this:

[image]

```
<form class="form" action="categories.php<?=((isset($_GET['edit']))?'?edit=.$edit_id':'');?>" method="post">
```

Why is it not getting the `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are setting it as a literal string. try

```
action="categories.php<?php echo (isset($_GET['edit'])) ? '?edit='.$edit_id :'');?>"
```

Comment: thanks men it works but i thought this was a shortcut i saw it working by someone else

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues going on here:

- You are trying to use variables inside single quotes
- You are using string concatenation from within a string, which is effectively a period

Try this:

```
<?php
   // We can check this way since you sanitize it at the top
   $param = is_numeric($edit_id) ? 'edit='.$edit_id : '';
?>
<form 
   class="form" 
   action="categories.php<?php echo($param); ?>" 
   method="post">
```